# Expressing like for like comparisons

Tags: business-language

I am trying to research common reporting practice, but somehow fail to find the right keywords for Google.

Essentially when a large retailer compares their reports from last year to this year the year on year changes are frequently smaller than the investment in new business. There's a phrase that is commonly used for that which I cannot find. It's something like:

'outlet corrected sales' or 'outlet adjusted sales' does anyone know the correct terms for this?

Comment: As in *seasonally adjusted figures*?

Comment: @Kris except that this is not *seasonally adjusted* so much as adjusted for change in size of operation. But without more specific details it is difficult to say what notation I would give it. I was in the accountancy profession for over 40 years.

Comment: @WS2 However, I asked because the OP's questions seems to have a mixup. "Corrected/ adjusted" is not the same as like-to-like (no change in figures).

Comment: I am looking at number of outlets that I need to report on. I am really trying to generally find common approaches my using Google,  but cannot find any relevant search terms. I believe Marks and Spencers and other supermarkets report like this in the UK. Looked over some of their reports but could not find it either.

Comment: it's 'like for like' in the sense that if I have a figures over 100 outlets and figures over 120 outlets the next year, I want to report on growth based on what has changed over the year without considering the 20 new outlets.

Comment: @Kris I think the point he is making is that the year on year comparisons are invalidated by the fact that new operations have been added in the current year. Hence, in business parlance, one is 'comparing apples with oranges'. The term I would use would be 'adjusted for change in number of outlets'. But even that could be criticised since one might not expect a directly proportionate rise in sales with an increase in numbers of shops.

Comment: Ah yes, I get it now. Figures for a fixed set (of outlets/ etc.) across years. Hmm, there must be a term for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think OP is talking about

> [Sales per unit area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sales_per_unit_area)

These are usually specified as *annual sales **per square foot/metre** of retail outlets*.

The concept of *per individual outlet/store* isn't very useful in most contexts, since it makes no sense to classify a large out-of-town "megastore" as somehow comparable to a small local outlet owned and operated by the same organisation.

Comment: I found some more complex accountancy methods, but this is probably the most suitable. Thanks.

Comment: @DHK: I really don't think "sales per retail outlet" would normally be seen as a meaningful performance metric. But I must admit I'd say the same about "revenue per employee", since at any given time a company might suddenly outsource/subcontract significant chunks of its operation, or take over a huge subsidiary in a low-wage country, for example. But for what it's worth, apparently [Coca Cola say](http://www.advfn.com/exchanges/NYSE/KO/financials) their Revenue per Employee is $358,760. Or perhaps that's just something an interested industry analyst calculated for some reason.